# Solve $f(x)\mid g^2(x)+1$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

We know that if $p\in \mathbb P$ and $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ then we can find $t\in\mathbb Z$ such that $p\mid t^2+1.$

> For what polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$, we can find $g(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ such that $f(x)\mid g^2(x)+1$?

Let $g^2(x)+1=f(x)h(x),h(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$, we get that $f(x)g(x)=0$ has no real roots. Hence $$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(a_ix^2+b_ix+c_i),(b_i^2-4a_ic_i<0,a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb R).$$

My idea is factor $g^2(x)+1$ in $C[x]:$ $$g^2(x)+1=(g(x)+I)(g(x)-I)=f(x)h(x).$$
But how to go on now ?

Comment: If $f$ is monic and irreducible, the ring $\mathcal O_f =\mathbf Z[x]/f(x)$ is an order in the ring of integers of a number field. Then you are asking: when is $i \in \mathcal O_f$? I'd be surprised if there was a simple criterion.